# Java MySQL Iterate Backwards through ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

I've executed a query that returns a `ResultSet` of data that I would like to iterate backwards over. In a for loop it would look like this:

```
for (int i = MAX; i >=0; i--){
     // do something
}
```

The only problem is I don't have a a column in my DB that is perfectly sequential, instead I have an id that is unique, but sometimes skips numbers. So, using the actual result set, is there some way I can do `while(set.next()) {...}` but in reverse? Thanks.

Comment: Being able to "scroll in reverse" depends less on "Java" or "JDBC" ... than it depends on your database supporting a "scrollable cursor", and specifying it when you open your query.  For example: http://www.java2novice.com/jdbc/scroll-read-only/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can traverse a resultset backwards if you have a scrollable resultset.You can get this by doing

`ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`when creating the statement.

Then you can use resultset.last() to get to the last entry and traverse backwards using resultset.previous()

Edit: If you want results in descending order of the non-sequential ids that you mentioned, you can retrieve the resultset in descending order by doing `order by id desc` and then traverse the resultset normally

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :D